The Firebase Admin SDK always returns the ID string
It always returns it, even without printing it.
{ "name": "projects/MY_PROJECT/messages/0:1726116770149249%9feb7b149feb7b14" }
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message
How can I handle this?
use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials;
use Google\Auth\HttpHandler\HttpHandlerFactory;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

function send_fcm_notify($token, $title, $message) {
        $credential = new ServiceAccountCredentials(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging",
                json_decode(file_get_contents("MY-KEY.json"), true)
        );

        $tokenAuth = $credential->fetchAuthToken(HttpHandlerFactory::build());

        $ch = curl_init(https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY-PROJECT/messages:send);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Bearer '.$tokenAuth['access_token']
        ]);
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{
                "message": {
                    "token": "'.$token.'",
                    "notification": {
                        "title": "'.$title.'",
                        "body": "'.$message.'"
                    }
                }
            }');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "post");
        curl_exec($ch);
        //$response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        //return $response;
        //echo $response;
}

The response should be printed only when intended.
